# adding animate css to zoomable circle packing D3

Tags: javascript, css, animation, d3.js

So I did **a lot of research** and googled everything I could but cannot find the proper way to doing it. I've used [Zoomable Circle Packing](https://bl.ocks.org/fdlk/076469462d00ba39960f854df9acda56) and that was awesome. I want to extend it and add new features, but I got stuck. 
I think I'm close to the solution, but cannot find the proper way. 
I have some text over circles, which I want to add animations on the text, after clicking on the circles. The problem is, when animation begins to run, all of the text lose their transform-origin (and transform: translate which is dynamic) and the animation runs. after though, they came back to their positions, at the center of the circle which they're belong to.
here is the zoom code which applies transform:

```
function zoomTo(v) {
var k = diameter / v[2];
view = v;
setTimeout(() => {  //my code for generating animations
  text.style('animation', 'flip 2s')
}, 5000);

node.attr("transform", function (d) {
  return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")";
})

circle.attr("r", function (d) {
  return d.r * k;
});
```

}
you can see my code seperated with a setTimeout, which applies the animation after 5 seconds. setTimeout is used to make it more clear and distinguish between my code and the base code which is written for the zoom functionality.
[flip animation](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css/blob/2897a5b148efbe294b0f897c0a575e847b05a381/animate.css#L1902) is being used from animate.css. 
I've adding text code in order to be more clear:

```
var text = g.selectAll("text")
.data(nodes)
.enter().append("text")
.attr("class", "label")
.style("font-size", function (d) {
  if (d.depth == 1) {
    d.fontSize = 72;
    return '72px';
  }
  if (d.r / 2 > 5 && d.r / 2 < 20) {
    d.fontSize = d.r / 2;
    return d.r / 2 + 'px';
  }
  if (d.r > 20) {
    d.fontSize = 18;
    return '18px';
  }
  d.fontSize = 8;
  return '8px';
})
.style("fill-opacity", function (d) {
  return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0;
})
.style("display", function (d) {
  return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none";
})
.text(function (d) {
  return d.data.name;
})
.on('mouseenter', function (d) {
  console.log(d3.select(this).node().getBBox().width);
  
  let newSize = d.fontSize + 10;
  d3.select(this).transition().duration(250).ease(d3.easeLinear).style("font-size", newSize + 'px')
  // var rectangle = svg.append("rect")
  //   .attr("x", d.x - d3.select(this).node().getBBox().width/2)
  //   .attr("y", d.y - d3.select(this).node().getBBox().height/2)
  //   .attr("width", d3.select(this).node().getBBox().width)
  //   .attr("height", d3.select(this).node().getBBox().height)
  //   .attr('fill', 'white')
})
.on('mouseleave', function (d) {
  d3.select(this).transition().duration(250).ease(d3.easeLinear).style("font-size", d.fontSize + 'px')
})
```

**And there is a [working example](http://aalicode.ir/QwMORUfxyk/) of the code with the problem (please wait 5 seconds after opening the page. then with click to every circle you can see the problem)**
Problem is that the animation will override the transform: translate (x,y) which applied by d3 (zoomTo function). 
Many Thanks

Comment: seems animation plays for children of a node, in position of their parent.